# How to get the frame size (orientation dependent) in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I used [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] to get the frame size in Objective-C, for example 1024x768 in iPad.

However, when I switch the screen orientation, like from portrait to landscape, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] still returns the same value.

How to get the frame size (orientation dependent) ? (For example, 1024x768 when in portrait and 768x1024 in landscape)

Thanks

---

Update: problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
CGRect rect = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame ;
```

it will return you frame of application screen area in points (i.e. entire screen minus status bar if visible)

Comment: I tried it before, it does not update even the orientation changes

Comment: You could consider registering for the orientation change notification, Define `hardcoded` **rect** for orientation and  use that accordingly.

Comment: Your answer is not correct. I solved the problem by getting the  orientation and use the [UIScreen mainScreen] bounds.width or .height according to that orientation.

Comment: What if,you try with using **[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame.width or .height according to that orientation**